# More space used than it adds up to

Tags: raspbian, pi-4, filesystem

So I have a raspberry pi 4 4GB with a 32GB running raspbian desktop (without extra apps). Its used for plex and transmission.

df -h output :

```
/dev/root        30G   28G  212M 100% /
devtmpfs        1.6G     0  1.6G   0% /dev
tmpfs           1.7G  8.0K  1.7G   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs           1.7G  8.5M  1.7G   1% /run
tmpfs           5.0M  4.0K  5.0M   1% /run/lock
tmpfs           1.7G     0  1.7G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/mmcblk0p1  253M   53M  200M  21% /boot
/dev/sda1       916G  107G  763G  13% /mnt/mydisk
tmpfs           348M     0  348M   0% /run/user/1000
```

But du -h output adds up only to 111G (and 107 are coming from the hard drive).
I tried expanding the file system but it changed nothing .
So whats taking up the extra space?

Comment: I've seen that sometimes, the output by `df` is not current. Does rebooting help?

Comment: Unmount /dev/sda1 and have a look whether there's anything hidden in /mnt or /mnt/mydisk.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so I figured it out I unmounted the external HDD and found out that in my mnt folder I also had a duplicate of something that was downloaded on the HDD (I guess transmision downloaded in that folder on a boot when the HDD was not pluged in). Thanks @Dougie for the idea.

Comment: Please accept your own answer with a click on the tick on its left side. Only this will finish the question and it will not pop up again year for year.

Answer (score 1):

On EXT file systems 5% of the unused partition space is reserved to `root`. This reserved space is not reported by `df`.

Another chunk of your partition will be used to hold internal structures of the EXT file system such as the journal or inodes table. Its size will depend on how the partition was used: lots of files and symlinks and a large journal will take more space than a partition with a few large files and no journal. There are equivalent structures for other filesystems as well, e.g. on NTFS partitions you have the MFT.

Comment: I figured that the file system takes some extra space but we are talking about 25GB